# how to add double quotes for each array elements in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below format

```
$array = ["a, b, c, d"]
```

But I want to convert the array like below format

```
$array = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

I have already googling about this issue but can't get the desire solution yet.

Anybody help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the contents of the string at index `0` and use that as your new array. The explode function will create an array based on the delimiter specified.

```
$array = ["a, b, c, d"];
$array = explode(',', $array[0]);
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d )
```

Here I have exploded the string in your array `"a, b, c, d"` based on the comma `,` delimiter. This means that you will get an array of elements where the comma indicates the separation between each element in the array.

Comment: ...It's done. I accept this answer because it is explained very nicely. All of the others answers also correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$array = ["a, b, c, d"];
$array_1 = explode(', ', $array[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this with explode()

The explode() function breaks a string into an array.

**Note**: The "separator" parameter cannot be an empty string.

**Note**: This function is binary-safe.

```
$array = ["a, b, c, d"];
$array = explode(',', $array[0]);
print_r($array);
```